# Are there methods to uniquely create an ID, that prevent masquerading

Tags: hash, public-key-infrastructure

I'm not sure if this is the right place, but I have an idea for a database kind of like a wiki, that would NOT have editors, and would have the following requirements:

- Any user can start with using their real name or a pseudonym
- Anyone can later switch to using their real name (no reversals to a pseudonym or changing pseudonyms)
- Identity is assured using some combination of a private/public key system and hashing (data is hashed with the content and the key of the user that created it).
- Any user can add data and/or comments to anything (but cannot delete another users data).
- A user can "delete" their own data, which just creates a new version of the same "chunk". This is visible and browsable by anyone.
- Any user browsing/reading the database can filter the raw data itself by any desired means. For instance: only show data from real-named users, only show data that hasn't been changed, only show data that has been verified or confirmed by X number of other real-named users, etc.

I see some issues which might be fixable or unsurmountable:

- Verification of real name. This could involve some trust system, where multiple (unrelated) parties have to sign off on who you are (not on the content of your data, but just your identity).
- For two people that share the same name, there will need to be some additional name field, maybe an incrementing number.
- If you lose your private key, how do you post again? Could there again be a way where a quorum of the verification parties ID the real you, as you, and your private key can be returned? (this sets up issues with storing the key)
- Preventing masquerading for the pseudonym accounts (maybe data can be filtered by only those who will actually sign their name), so that the hackers/spammers don't overwhelm the system with bad or fake data, that is seemly supported by a huge body (of fake people).

My question is, where do I go to learn about how this might be implemented, or contacts I can ask about the details that need to be fleshed out or refined?

**additions to address others**

The real name is important, because there has to be trust. I could foresee this taking the place of a scientific journal (unlike Wikipedia, that doesn't allow original research). For instance, a researcher at a university or foundation could be verified as such (once) by said foundation, and then whatever work they do on there (whether, facts, opinions, moderation, etc) will be attached to them. And as far as the ID, I expect that the actual computer-readable id will be some hash or alphanumeric string, but I mean the public-facing name should also indicate who this person is maybe with an additional string or number. Two Adam Joneses are two different people, and one should not be able to impersonate the work of the other.

I want a reputation system in a way, but I also want it to be very democratic. For instance, one problem with some publication houses is that they will not take information from anyone without the proper connections or credentials. Admittedly, it's harder today to produce original research without having gone through some formal academic system, but it is possible. Science doesn't (shouldn't) care who figured out and wrote up the truth, only that those facts are disseminated. This is also why I think that the person verification needs to be separated from a reputation system: anyone can post (and there will be speculations, opinions, lies, and crap), not just those in ivory towers. And just like today, where some well respected person in one field can make asinine comments in another, it doesn't mean that the institution that hired them for their work in the first field is to blame or should be looked down upon for their comments in the other.

Finally, this would most definitely -not- be like Wikipedia's editor-based system. There is a reason so many academics have thrown up their hands with Wikipedia: editors with axes to grind and either poor understanding of the articles they're editing, or just a "no one else can touch this, this is mine" attitude, make it very much a lower-tier source of information. Instead of editing, one should be able to comment on others work, or flag sections as fact, opinion, speculation, lies, etc. And then the user can decide which factors they want to use to filter all of this: only people verified by so-and-so, or only people with X many posts/articles/etc that have been also verified by academic institutions etc.

Comment: yes, and Ill be publishing software to git soon.  Pm me your use cases and Ill make sure the foundation is correct for your needs. Makerofthings7 at gmail

Comment: If you are asking for general feedback on the system, that is to broad to fit this site. If you are looking for resources to learn more, that is not on topic either.

Comment: @LamonteCristo - what would be of much better value is to post an answer with an outline of what your software will do, and then a link to it, rather than a slightly self promoting comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need a public/private key system, such as PGP.

If a user is real-named or not could be a flag in the key, or even not care about it. Does it really matter if "Adam Jones" is a real name or a pseudonym?

> Verification of real name

You can reuse PGP Web of Trust model.

> For two people that share the same name, there will need to be some additional name field, maybe an incrementing number.

Key ids would be preferable. After all, it is the key that matters.

> If you lose your private key, how do you post again?

You can't. Have the user create a new key (account). You may have a number of other users attests that this new Adam Jones is the same as the previous one (and let the readers believe it or not), but trying to implement a protocol for reassigning users like that… **No**.

> Preventing masquerading for the pseudonym accounts (maybe data can be filtered by only those who will actually sign their name), so that the hackers/spammers don't overwhelm the system with bad or fake data, that is seemly supported by a huge body (of fake people).

I would base this on a reputation system. Additionally, having more good faith editors than malicious ones (and proper tools to easily revert spam) would be important for overcoming this. It worked for wikipedia.

Comment: I added additional text to the question to address some of your responses.

Comment: Although my question was overly broad, you provided the most comprehensive feedback (if not an answer per se).

Answer (score 0):

Only one point to address. The user's private key. If it's really a private key, you cannot restore it because you don't know it. If you know it, it's not a *private* key. How do you assure it's not compromised in transit from user to system, or upon restoration, from system to user? How do you assure the user that nobody will get his private key during a compromise of your system? My private key stays in *my* pocket, and if you need it, I don't need you. Philosophically speaking, that is. :)

Comment: That's one of the big things I didn't know how to get around. I understand the PGP model. However, for this to work, one would need to "sign" their work (all of it), and it has to be impossible for anyone else to sign it. And if their computer gives up the ghost, there has to be continuity for them to continue again.

Comment: They shouldn't be storing their private key on their computer anyway, it should be in some removable device, key card maybe, or at least an encrypted USB stick. I don't think, absent some version of WOT verification that continuity is _your_ problem. The security of the key is their problem, and loss of their continuity is one of the consequences they face for failure. A side thought, food for thought for you project, not a reply: How will you handle it when a user needs to update to a new key? Cross-sign the new key with the old one? Re-validate with WOT model?. & Etc.